# Custom Apex trigger creating duplicate records

Tags: apex, trigger

I'm hoping for some help with some Apex code and/or other troubleshooting ideas if the code ends up looking okay. I'm a long-time SF Admin but super new to Apex (and to coding in general), and I'm trying to fix some code written by others, which is causing duplicate ABC Program Contact (custom object) records to be created, when only one record should be created as a result of this code.

I'd love to know if it seems like an issue within this code (and if so, any tips to fix it), or if I should be looking elsewhere for the cause of these duplicate records. Any insight is appreciated!

**Trigger:**

```
    trigger ABCApplicationTriggers on ABC_Application__c (before insert, before update, after update) {

    if(Trigger.isInsert && Trigger.isBefore)
        ABCApplicationTriggerHandler.handleBeforeApplicationInsert(Trigger.new);

    if(Trigger.isUpdate && Trigger.isBefore)
        ABCApplicationTriggerHandler.handleAfterApplicationUpdate(Trigger.new, Trigger.oldMap);

}
```

**Trigger Handler:**

```
    public class ABCApplicationTriggerHandler {
  public static void handleBeforeApplicationInsert(list<ABC_Application__c> newApplications)
  {
      if(application.Student_Application__c)
        application.ABC_Program_Student__c = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c;
      else if(application.Instructor_Application__c)
        application.ABC_Program_Instructor__c = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c;
    }
  }

  public static void handleAfterApplicationUpdate(list<ABC_Application__c> updatedApplications, map<Id, ABC_Application__c> oldApplications)
  {

    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    Map<Id, Contact> applicationContactMap = new Map<Id, Contact>();
    List<ABC_Application__c> acceptedApplications = new List<ABC_Application__c>();
    Map<String, ABC_Program_Contact__c> programContacts = new Map<String, ABC_Program_Contact__c>();

    Contact contact;
    
    Map<String, ABC_Application_Sync_Fields__c> contactJobApplicationFieldMapping = new Map<String, ABC_Application_Sync_Fields__c>();
    String contactStringFields = '';
    for(ABC_Application_Sync_Fields__c setting:[select Name, Application_Field__c, Destination_Field__c from ABC_Application_Sync_Fields__c where Destination_Object__c = 'Contact'])
    {
      contactJobApplicationFieldMapping.put(setting.Name, setting);
      contactStringFields += ', ' + setting.Destination_Field__c;
    }

    Map<String, RecordType> contactRecordTypeMap = new Map<String, RecordType>();
    Set<Id> programContactRecordTypes = new Set<Id>();
    for(RecordType recordType:[select Id, Name from RecordType where sObjectType = 'Contact'])
    {
      contactRecordTypeMap.put(recordType.Name, recordType);
      if (recordType.Name == 'Program' || recordType.Name == 'Instructor' || recordType.Name == 'Student') programContactRecordTypes.add(recordType.Id);
    }


    for(ABC_Application__c application:updatedApplications)
    {
      if((application.Application_Status__c == 'Confirmed' && oldApplications.get(application.Id).Application_Status__c != 'Confirmed')) 
      {    
        RecordType contactRecordType = contactRecordTypeMap.get('Program');      
     
        String applicationLastName = application.Last_Name__c;
        String applicationFirstName = application.First_Name__c;
        Date applicationBirthDate = application.Birthdate__c;
        String sqlStatement = 'select Id, LastName, FirstName, BirthDate';
        if(contactStringFields != '')
          sqlStatement += contactStringFields;
        
        sqlStatement += ' from Contact where FirstName = :applicationFirstName and LastName = :applicationLastName and BirthDate = :applicationBirthDate and RecordTypeId in :programContactRecordTypes';

        list<Contact> existingContacts = Database.query(sqlStatement); 
        if(!existingContacts.isEmpty())
        {
          contact = existingContacts[0];
          contact.RecordTypeId = contactRecordType.Id;
        }
        else
          contact = new Contact(LastName = application.Last_Name__c, FirstName = application.First_Name__c, BirthDate = application.Birthdate__c, RecordTypeId = contactRecordType.Id);

        for(String mapping:contactJobApplicationFieldMapping.keyset())
        {
          contact.put(contactJobApplicationFieldMapping.get(mapping).Destination_Field__c, application.get(contactJobApplicationFieldMapping.get(mapping).Application_Field__c));
        }
                
               if (application.Record_Type_Name__c.contains('Program A')) contact.ABC_Program__c = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c ;
                else if (application.Record_Type_Name__c.contains('Program B')) contact.XYZ_Program__c  = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c ;
                else if (application.Record_Type_Name__c.contains('Program C')) contact.ABC_Program__c = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c;
                else if (application.Record_Type_Name__c.contains('Program D')) contact.XYZ_Program__c = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c;

        acceptedApplications.add(application);
        applicationContactMap.put(application.Id, contact);

        contacts.add(contact);

      }
    }

    if(!contacts.isEmpty())
      upsert contacts;

    Map<String, RecordType> abcProgramContactRecordTypeMap = new Map<String, RecordType>();
    for(RecordType recordType:[select Id, Name from RecordType where sObjectType = 'ABC_Program_Contact__c'])
    {
      abcProgramContactRecordTypeMap.put(recordType.Name, recordType);
    }

    for(ABC_Application__c application:acceptedApplications)
    {
      application.Contact__c = applicationContactMap.get(application.Id).Id;

      String key = String.valueOf(application.Contact__c) + String.ValueOf(application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c);
      programContacts.put(key, new ABC_Program_Contact__c(Contact__c = applicationContactMap.get(application.Id).Id, ABC_Program__c = application.ABC_Program_Lookup__c, RecordTypeId = abcProgramContactRecordTypeMap.get(application.Record_Type_Name__c).Id ));
    }

    if(!programContacts.values().isEmpty())
      insert programContacts.values();

    
   }

}
```

Comment: I think we're going to need a bit more information. In what way is the `ABC_Program_Contact__c` being duplicated? Is there already a `ABC_Program_Contact__c` before your trigger is being run (and this is creating just one record that's a duplicate of the existing one)? Or is it that this trigger is running and all of a sudden you have two of each `ABC_Program_Contact__c`?

Comment: Put another way: Let's say you end up with 2 custom contacts. Do you start with 0 (both duplicates created at the same time) or 1 (one existing record, and a duplicate is created)?

Comment: Hi Derek - thanks for your comment! I'm starting with 0 ABC_Program_Contact__c records, and both duplicates are created at the same time.

Comment: Ok, then you're going to need to look for any flows for `ABC_Application__c` that optimize for "Actions and Related Records" that have a field update action. If you still have Process Builder processes or Workflows, you'd need to look at those as well. Field update actions (except in flows optimized for fast field updates) will cause triggers to be run a second time. We don't have any great ways to deal with that (or even detect that it's happening), but there are ways around it. I'll wait to get a confirmation before working on an answer.